# How to enable a UI botton in ViewController A upon on row selection in TableViewController B. Both View controllers are nested in TabarController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller

I have two view controllers in tab bar controller. ViewControllerA has two buttons (MybuttonA and MybuttonB with enabled box unchecked in storyboard). ViewControllerB is a TableViewController. I would like to enable buttons in ViewControllerA upon selecting specific rows in ViewControllerB table.

Greatly appreciate any help...

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface  ViewControllerA : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIButton * MybuttonA;
    IBOutlet UIButton * MybuttonB;

}
-(IBAction)mybuttonaction:(id)sender;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *MybuttonA;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *MybuttonB;

@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerA ()
@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
@synthesize MybuttonA;
@synthesize MybuttonB;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(IBAction)mybuttonaction:(id)sender{
NSString * link = @"https://google.com";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]];
 }
```

ViewControllerB.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerB : UITableViewController{

    ViewControllerA *viewcontrollerA;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewControllerA *viewcontrollerA;
@end
```

ViewControllerB.m

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerB () {

}

@end

@implementation ViewControllerB
@synthesize  viewcontrollerA;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

   self.title = @"CONTENTS";

     self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
     [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(reload)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self reload];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

}

#pragma mark - Table View

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {return 1;}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 {return 5;}
 }

     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Cell #%d", indexPath.row];

}

return cell;
}



 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString* value = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;



    if ([value isEqual:@"1"]){
    viewcontrollerA.MybuttonA.enabled=YES;

    }


    else if ([value isEqual:@"2"])
    {
                viewcontrollerA.MybuttonB.enabled=YES;

    }


    }



else {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
 }


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ViewControllerB`, add the following line to `viewDidLoad`:

```
viewControllerA = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Then, the rest of your code should work as you have it.

Note that you should generally use `self.viewControllerA` instead of accessing the iVar directly unless you have a good reason for it.  :-)

Comment: I have implemented both suggestions and the code stops at breakpoint

Comment: self.viewcontrollerA.MyButtonA.enabled=YES;

Comment: If the code stops at a breakpoint, then hit run so that it continues.  :)

Comment: Now I ran into another trouble. I wanted to embed both the ViewControllerA and ViewControllerB in NavigationControllers which are inturn nested in tabbarcontroller.

Comment: I tried several variations of the code - but the Buttons does not get enabled. If I remove the navigation controllers, Mybutton does not push another ViewControllerC! I am stuck with what to do.

Comment: Hi Sivon, since this is about something else, please post it as a new question with the relevant information so that others can help you in their areas of expertise as well!